# Lex case insensitive word detection

Tags: c, lex

I need to treate a string in C where certain words, if present, have to be converted to uppercase. My first choice was to work it in LEX something like this:

```
%%
word1    {setToUppercase(yytext);RETURN WORD1;}
word2    {setToUppercase(yytext);RETURN WORD2;}
word3    {setToUppercase(yytext);RETURN WORD3;}
%%
```

The problem I see is that I don't get to detect if some of the chars are uppercase (f.e. Word1, wOrd1...). This could mean a one by one listing:

```
%%
word1   |
Word1   |
WOrd1   
 {setToUppercase(yytext);RETURN WORD1;}

%%
```

Is there a way of defining that this especific tokens are to be compared in a case insensitive mode? I have found that I can compile the lexer to be case insensitive, but this can affect other pars of my program.

If not, any workaround suggestion?

Comment: could you preprocess (downcase certain words) before lexing?

Comment: In fact this is already a preprocesing for another lexing process. My problem is how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that the way that works is this one:

```
(W|w)(O|o)(R|r)(D|d) {setToUppercase(yytext);}
```

Comment: That's what you get for using ancient tools. ;-)

Comment: Bear Grylls of programing :)

Comment: Back in the day, I used to paste 26 definitions into my lex files: `A [Aa]`, `B [Bb]`, ..., and then you can write `{W}{O}{R}{D}`. Although it's not much shorter than `[Ww][Oo][Rr][Dd]`, it's a bit easier to type. `flex` is better.

Answer (score 24):

You could set case-insensitivity in the `.l` file:

```
%option caseless
```

You could call `flex -i`.

Or you could state individual rules to be case-insensitive:

```
(?i:word)
```

Comment: I have read about that option, but, as I understood that implies that every token in the lexer will be case insensitive, isn't it?

Comment: @jordi: See extended answer. Assuming you use `flex`; I have no experience with `lex` and don't know whether it supports this.

Comment: Ups. Sorry. I'll try that.

Comment: Looks like it is not supported in lex. I found another way.

Comment: Regarding **f**lex, `(?i:word)` is documented here: http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Patterns.html . You can use after version 2.5.34.

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple give your patterns and actions as it is,don't worry.
While compiling give it as,
**lex -i filename.l**
This is on LINUX systems.